# xUnit.net: Why do these 2 equivalent tests have different results?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, xunit.net, surrogate-pairs

For some reason, this test utilizing `InlineData` fails in xUnit:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("\uD800", 1)]
public static void HasLength(string s, int length)
{
    Assert.Equal(length, s.Length);
}
```

while this, which uses `MemberData`, passes:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> HasLength_TestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { "\uD800", 1 };
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(HasLength_TestData))]
public static void HasLength(string s, int length)
{
    Assert.Equal(length, s.Length);
}
```

What is the reason for this? Have I discovered a bug in xUnit.net? (I think it may have something to do with the fact that `\uD800` is a [surrogate character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF), and it's somehow getting translated to 2 characters when passing thru `InlineData`. Not sure why, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicolay's answer doesn't answer the question, but does [link](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/11/07/when-is-a-string-not-a-string/) to it:

Attribute values are stored using UTF-8, and an isolated high surrogate cannot successfully be converted from UTF-16.

Here's a (VB.NET) [LinqPad query](http://share.linqpad.net/vb3eoi.linq) confirming the situation.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now- so it isn't a bug in xUnit, but this is built-in to the .NET Framework. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bug.

If you want to represent a value greater than U+FFFF in UTF-16, you need to use two UTF-16 code units: a high surrogate (in the range 0xD800 to 0xDBFF) followed by a low surrogate (in the range 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF). So a high surrogate on its own makes no sense. It’s a valid UTF-16 code unit in itself, but it only has meaning when followed by a low surrogate.

More info in this article http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/11/07/when-is-a-string-not-a-string/